# Running Wordpress code obtained from Github repo

Tags: wordpress, github

I'm collaborating with a friend on a Wordpress blog for work, whose code is on a Github repo, and is hosted on Amazon EC2.

I have never used Wordpress before, so this question might sound dumb to experts ...

Question : how do I preview my changes to the blog ? Once I make a change to the code (after I have cloned the repo from Github) what shall I run locally so I can see the blog as it would be if I had done the change online through my Wordpress account ?

I can't start anything until I'm up and running, any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Unless you change the code of your Wordpress blog you only change the content of your database which is possibly on the same EC2 instance as the blog. If you want to see the same locally you will have to set up the same blog on your local machine and add the same posts locally.

But iirc you can preview blog posts in Wordpress so you don't need to test them locally. Just don't publish your posts.